# Оценка эффективности

Tags: c#

Как оценить скорость обработки программы. С помощью ProgressBar?

Comment: вам отображать или замерять для себя?

Comment: Если можно то отображать и замерять.

Comment: Даже необязательно ProgressBar// Можно любыми способами, посути надо оценить эффективность обработки  моей проги по иверсии байт.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть специальные программы - профилировщики, которые умеют замерять время работы отдельных функций. Если вам просто померять - используйте класс [StopWatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx). А вот [тут](http://j-coder.blogspot.com/2011/07/stopwatch.html) есть хорошие примеры использования.